# Partitioning disk to install Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, swap

I tried to install Ubuntu without doing any research and I ended up formatting the whole disk, losing all my data, just to have a **gpt** partition table.

Now I am not afraid of making mistakes because I already lost everything, but I would like to complete the installation properly.

I need to create some partition where to install Ubuntu, so far I created an EFI partition in FAT32, a ROOT one in ext4 and SWAP one *cleared*.

After having made the partitioning effective, the SWAP shows something like a warning and the file system displays as *unknown*

[image]

[image]

Is the *unknown* all right or should I format the partition with the *linux-swap* option?

Also I really don't know what I am doing, will my laptop understand that I gave him a **boot** and a swap partition? And do I need to create some other partition before to try installing Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to create any partitions before installing Ubuntu, just have free nu-allocated space on your disk.

Comment: You don't need to create partitions manually. You can leave it to the installer. Nowadays you don't need a swap partition. A swapfile is used.

Comment: Be sure, if you want efi, that the installation media boots in this mode.

Comment: If data was important, what you should do before anything else is to try to recover it.  Recovery of lost data does require quite a bit of research to do well.  Fortunately we have google to find it.  You don't need a swap partition anymore, so can add space to root if you want.

Comment: If you have swap partition installer will find it and use it. You have to use Something Else install option to choose(change) partition that will be / (root). Since swap is unformatted, it often shown with issues. Live installer also mounts it, so to change partitions with gparted on live installer, you have to unmount it, swapoff.

Comment: @crip659 no worries, there was nothing important. All right I did it as you people suggested: I deleted all the partitions and let the installer to do its job. Now I got Ubuntu and will care about creating a swap file. Any other important thing I should take care of?

Comment: Ubuntu takes care of swapfile itself.  Google can find lots of interesting and important stuff about Ubuntu.  Just remember your password you make when installing(would write it down till you have it remembered).  Have fun, backup important data, make mistakes.

Comment: @crip659 ahaha thanks for the advices. I will try to have fun making mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

For good advice on the install process, see the official step-by-step instructions on how to properly prepare your system, prepare your installer, and install Ubuntu safely:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop

Simply follow the process in the tutorial. It works.

Comment: Yes I originally followed those steps, but I didn't had the option of installing alongside with windows, so I choose *something else* and messed up with the partitions, but I couldn't use the new partitions. So I messed up even more with them from Windows and then again in the Ubuntu installer, until my pc started to display "invalid partition table!" and the only os I could use was the Ubuntu trial in the usb. I guess I needed to do some research before to mess around, but here we are. I hope that without having windows I am going to learn quickly how to use Linux.

Comment: A link to the steps you followed and clear description of your troubleshooting should be in your question. An incomplete question leads to unhelpful answers (like this) and wasted effort by the volunteers who want to help you.

Comment: You are right, but anyway after having created a new gpt partition table, the past lost any importance.

Answer (score -2):

If you got Ram more than = 8 Gigs, you need not to make Swap partition.
EFI about 120 MB for linux only or about 250MB for Dual-boot
Second Partition ( Target / ) more than 30 Gigs.
I always do the same...

Comment: EFI about 120 Gigs ??? Is there a typo? People usually talk about values below 1 GB.

Comment: my RAM is 8GB and I got 150GB of memory in total, I can't reserve 120GB for EFI whatever it is

Comment: @Davide It's not needed for EFI. Waaay less.

Comment: oh yes, he meant MB

Comment: Sorry it was a typo

Comment: 120MB is probably too **small** for EFI. Especially for a dual boot config. Have you noticed how large kernels are lately?

Comment: M using 200 MB for dual boot & 120 for linux only